# How can I drop outbound UDP packets without affecting the sender?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I am trying to suppress outbound UDP packets, without letting the producer of these packets know.
My idea was to use iptables to drop the packets like this:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -d 127.0.0.1 -j DROP
```

The problem is that the sending application gets -1 as the return value from sendto() instead of the number of bytes sent, which is then handled as an error.  I need the sending application to be unaware that its output is getting dropped.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you know which port the UDP traffic is destined to, you could redirect them to another port on localhost instead of dropping them. That way you could provide a listening sink which does absolutely nothing besides receiving packets. As the packets are now delivered, though not where they were originally destined, `sendto()` will not return -1 but instead bytes delivered.

An example of a sink would be something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use IO::Socket::INET;

# flush after every write
$| = 1;

my $sock;
my $data;

$socket = new IO::Socket::INET ( LocalPort => '55555', Proto => 'udp',);
while(1) { $socket->recv($data,1024); }
$socket->close();

# end of file.
```

What's above will happily sit, forever, on port 55555 and do nothing with data it receives. Next thing is to redirect packets destined, to say anything destined to any host for port 555 to local port 55555 instead:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 555 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:55555
```

Restrict the above rule with appropriate source/destination address specification, in case you don't feel like redirecting all traffic to all destinations for port 555.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried doing something similar by rewriting the destination IP in the NAT table, but it didn't work for my case because it didn't affect the sender's existing UDP sockets.  If I restarted the sender, then the packets were redirected, but I am looking for a way to toggle this on and off without affecting the sender.

Answer (score 1):

Semi's asnwer gave me an idea that worked: first redirect to a different port then use an INPUT rule to drop the traffic (which works as expected).

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 555 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:55555
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p udp --dport 55555 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nftables`:

```
nft add table nat
nft add chain nat drop_my_udp_app {type nat hook output priority 0\;}
nft add rule nat drop_my_udp_app ip protocol udp udp dport 555 drop
```

Apparently drop in `nat` table (unlike in `filter` table) does not result in application being notified with -1 during `sendto` (kernel version 4.19).

If you have other NAT rules/chains, you probably would like to adjust chain priority.

Comment: With kernel 5.15.0 (Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS), sender gets notified even with this solution:

`Failed to write to socket: fwrite(): send of 325 bytes failed with errno=1 Operation not permitted`